# Dynamic Actions on a WCF-Custom Biztalk SQL port?

Tags: sql, wcf, dynamic, biztalk

So i have an orchestration that successfully does everything i need it to.  Now, i want to reuse the logic in the orchestration, but with a set of slightly different data sources.  Rather than copy and paste the orchestration into another one and having to use a decision tree to choose which orchestration to call, I was thinking of making my calls to SQL a little more dynamic.

For example, lets say i have a stored procedure called spGetUSCust.  I have coded the orchestration to call the SQL server via a send/receive port with an operation of GetCust on it.  It was generated using a strongly typed method so the response message is of a type spGetUSCustResponse.

I now want to call spGetCACust on the same SQL server.  The responding data is in the exact same format (structure) as the US stored proc, but they have different names.

So my question is, can i do this by setting the action on the message that will be going to the port within the code?  Since my response is strongly typed, will it cause a problem that the response will be really coming from the CA procedure and not the US one?  If so, how do i solve that?  I could go with generic responses, but they return XML ANY fields and i need to map these responses for additional use in the orchestration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an Message Assignment Shape, you can set the WCF.Action property on the request message like this:

MySQLRequest(WCF.Action)="TypedProcedure/dbo/spGetUSCust";

You can use the same physical Port and will have to remove any content in the Action Mapping section.

However, because the Request Messages are different types, you will need two Orchestration Ports, one US, one CA.